# XPathの//item[1]とdescendant-or-self::item[1]の違い

Tags: xml, xpath, xsl

非常に基本的なことなのでしょうけれども掲題の違いがわかりません．例えば次のようなXMLがあったとします．

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <item attr1="val1" attr2="val2">
        <item attr3="val3">
            <item attr4="val4">
                <item attr5="val5"/>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</root>
```

これに対して次のようなスタイルシートを適用すると

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <p1-1>
                <xsl:copy-of select="//item"/>
            </p1-1>
            <p1-2>
                <xsl:copy-of select="descendant-or-self::item"/>
            </p1-2>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

p1-1とp1-2には同じ次の内容のノードが選択されます．

```
  <item attr1="val1" attr2="val2">
           <item attr3="val3">
                 <item attr4="val4">
                       <item attr5="val5"/>
                 </item>
           </item>
     </item>
  <item attr3="val3">
              <item attr4="val4">
                    <item attr5="val5"/>
              </item>
        </item>
  <item attr4="val4">
                 <item attr5="val5"/>
           </item>
  <item attr5="val5"/>
```

ところがこれを

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <p1-1>
            <xsl:copy-of select="//item[1]"/>
        </p1-1>
        <p1-2>
            <xsl:copy-of select="descendant-or-self::item[1]"/>
        </p1-2>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

と変えると

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <p1-1>
      <item attr1="val1" attr2="val2">
          <item attr3="val3">
              <item attr4="val4">
                   <item attr5="val5"/>
              </item>
           </item>
      </item>
      <item attr3="val3">
          <item attr4="val4">
              <item attr5="val5"/>
          </item>
      </item>
      <item attr4="val4">
          <item attr5="val5"/>
      </item>
      <item attr5="val5"/>
   </p1-1>
   <p1-2>
       <item attr1="val1" attr2="val2">
           <item attr3="val3">
               <item attr4="val4">
                   <item attr5="val5"/>
               </item>
           </item>
       </item>
   </p1-2>
</root>
```

という結果となります．predicate（述語）の[1]は異なる結果をもたらします．

XPathの仕様によれば簡略記述の//item[1]は(fn:root(self::node()) treat as document-node())/descendant-or-self::node()/child::item[1]に等しくなります．

[3.2 Path Expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#doc-xpath-PathExpr)

> A "//" at the beginning of a path expression is an abbreviation for the initial steps (fn:root(self::node()) treat as document-node())/descendant-or-self::node()/ (however, "//" by itself is not a valid path expression [err:XPST0003].)

すこしややこしいですが、簡単に言えばドキュメントノードの位置から見てdescendant-or-self::node()/child::item[1]とdescendant-or-self::item[1]はどう違うのか？

ということになるでしょうか？なぜ両者が異なる結果となるのかがよくわかりません．

説明いただける方おられましたらよろしくお願いいたします．

［追記］
ちなみに仕様には違う結果になると書いてあります．

[3.3.5 Abbreviated Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#abbrev)

> Note:The path expression //para[1] does not mean the same as the path expression /descendant::para[1]. The latter selects the first descendant para element; the former selects all descendant para elements that are the first para children of their respective parents.

Comment: これは質問者の誤った先入観により質問がされていました．考えてみれば異なる軸方向の要素の数え方の問題でしかありません．[n]とpredicateを書いたとして、ドキュメントオーダーの先の方を見る場合、child::*の場合は[1]は最初の子、[2]は２番目の子、...です．descendant::*の場合、[1]は最初の子、[2]は最初の子の最初の子、...となります．ですので２つのXPathの`//item[1]`と`descendant-or-self::item[1]`は異なる結果を生成して当たり前です．大変失礼いたしました．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> descendant-or-self::node()/child::item[1]は、子要素中のp‌​ositionなので常にprecedin‌​g-siblingで先頭から何番目か？d‌​‌​escendant-or-self:‌​:i‌​tem[1]は、コンテキストは各‌​子孫のitemなので、ともかくd‌​es‌​cendant-or-self::i‌​‌​temの１番目、preceding-si‌​blingなんて関係ない．という解釈でし‌​ょうか？

でいいと思います。一言で言えば、「述語`[1]`の付くのがグループかどうか？」となりそうです。

`//item[1]` = `descendant-or-self::node()/child::item[1]`

すでに @SOTH さんが述べてますが、`descendant-or-self::node()/child::item[1]`は、「まず descendant-or-self::node() を選んで、次にそこから child::item[1] を選ぶ」なので、各兄弟要素中で最初に出現する`item`要素がすべて選択されます。長子要素の集合が結果になり、サンプルでも複数の`item`要素が選択されています。

---

`descendant-or-self::item[1]` = `(descendant-or-self::item)[1]` = `(//item)[1]` = `(descendant-or-self::node()/child::item)[1]`

対して`descendant-or-self::item[1]`は、「まず `descendant-or-self::item` を選んでその結果グループの中から先頭の要素を述語`[1]`で選ぶ」です。グループの中から常に1個の要素を選ぶ訳ですから、サンプルでも1個の`item`要素‌​のみ選択されています。

---

まとめると、以下のようになります。

- `//item[1]`と`(//item)[1]`は述語の付く対象が異なる

  - `//item[1]`は任意の`item[1]`を選択
  - `(//item)[1]`は`item`グループの先頭を選択

Comment: `descendant-or-self::item[1]` = `(descendant-or-self::item)[1]` のような解釈だと、`ancestor-or-self::item[1]` のような場合の説明が付かなくなりませんか？

Answer (score 1):

`descendant-or-self::node()/child::item[1]` を２段階に分けるとすると、

「まず `descendant-or-self::node()/child::item` を選んで、次にそこから `[1]` を選ぶ」ではありません。
「まず `descendant-or-self::node()` を選んで、次にそこから `child::item[1]` を選ぶ」です。

つまり、

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//item[1]"/>
```

が行っていることは

```
<xsl:variable as="element(item)*" name="items" select="descendant-or-self::node()/child::item" />
<xsl:copy-of select="$items[1]" />
```

のようなものではありません。むしろ

```
<xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::node()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="child::item[1]" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

のようなものです。

---

要は、記号の優先順位に従って式を分割し、順に考えるだけです。

#### `descendant-or-self::item[1]` について考えると

context node から descendant-or-self 方向に見える 1 番目の `item` element を探します。
質問文の例では、`/root/item` が見つかります。それをピックアップして終了です。

#### `descendant-or-self::node()/child::item[1]` について考えると

`/` は `[]` より弱いので、全体の式はおよそ `descendant-or-self::node()`, `/`, `child::item[1]` に分割されます。これを順に考えていきます。

まず、`descendant-or-self::node()` で、context node から `descendant-or-self::node()` に該当する node すべて（`/root`, `/root/item`, `/root/item/item`, `/root/item/item/item` …など）を抽出します。

次に、`/` で、抽出した node 一つ一つに視点の出発点を移します。

最後に、`child::item[1]` で、各視点から、child 方向に見える 1 番目の `item` element を探します。
`/root` から見て child 方向に見える 1 番目の `item` element をピックアップする。
`/root/item` から見て child 方向に見える 1 番目の `item` element もピックアップする。
`/root/item/item` から見て child 方向に見える 1 番目の `item` element もまたピックアップする…。
`/root/item/item/item` から見て child 方向に見える 1 番目の `item` element もまたまたピックアップする…。
これを最初の `descendant-or-self::node()` で抽出した node すべてに対して行います。

Comment: もし考え違いがあったらすみません．`descendant-or-self::node()/child::item[1]`も`descendant-or-self::item[1]`もpredicateは`[position() eq 1]`のはずです．設問にも書きましたが、同じpredicateを適用して、各itemはみんなそれを満たすように考えられるのですが、違う結果となります．この理由が知りたいのです．両者でpredicateの意味はこうで違う結果になるんだということがわかれば理解に至ると思います．

Comment: predicate の意味は同じです。結果が違う理由は既述の通りです。

Comment: 回答でたとえている `<xsl:copy-of select="$items[1]" />` と `<xsl:copy-of select="child::item[1]" />` が、同じ結果になるはずだと思われるのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、単純にどうして同じにならないのかな～？と思っています．

Comment: `<xsl:copy-of select="(//item)[1]"/>`と括弧で括れば同じになりますね。

Comment: はい、それは理解できます．`()`は結果を取りだしてドキュメントオーダーに並べるのを強制ずるからですよね？？

Comment: 念のため確認ですが、本当に `<xsl:variable as="element(item)*" name="items" select="descendant-or-self::node()/child::item" /><xsl:copy-of select="$items[1]" />` と `<xsl:for-each select="descendant-or-self::node()"><xsl:copy-of select="child::item[1]" /></xsl:for-each>` とが同じになるはずだと考えてらっしゃるのですか？

Comment: いえ、そうは考えておりません．御例示の最初のコードは元の設問と等価ではありませんよね？最初に$itemを生成して、$items[1]とすれば、明らかに1個の要素が選択されます．この[1]はdescendant-or-self::node()/child::item[1]の[1]とは明らかに異なります．

Comment: それは「たとえ」だからです。もともとのご質問が、「1 + 2 * 3 が 9 にならない理由を知りたい」のような質問なので、XPath の式の優先順位による結果を、XSLT でたとえたまでです。

Comment: どうも今までの変な先入観があって理解に至っていないと思われるのですが、predicateの`[1]`は`[position() eq 1]`です．で`position()`はcontext positionです．`descendant-or-self::node()/child::item[1]`は、子要素中のpositionなので常にpreceding-siblingで先頭から何番目か？`d‌​escendant-or-self::i‌​tem[1]`は、コンテキストは各子孫のitemなので、ともかく`d‌​escendant-or-self::i‌​tem`の１番目、preceding-siblingなんて関係ない．という解釈でしょうか？

Comment: 回答に追記してみました。どうでしょう？